# Editors (TexStudio ) can't find package despite being installed by TexLive 2020

Tags: packages, ubuntu, linux, texlive-2020

Good Morning/Evening to all,

I'm new to Latex and so I've installed TexLive 2020 plus TeXstudio on my Ubuntu 20. Everything seems to be Ok, however, I keep getting errors in TeXStudio that package files can't be found. For example, I've installed biblatex using tlmgr and now if I enter:

`tlmgr install biblatex`

I get :

`tlmgr install: package already present: biblatex`

But when I try to use the package by typing \usepackage{biblatex} in my editor I get the error:

**File `biblatex.sty' not found. \usepackage**

I've added the paths to my .bashrc file and when type
`echo $PATH` I get:
`/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux`
As the first option; Which seems to be standard

When I use  `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` I get:

`/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`

Can anyone help me ? I'm going insane over here.

Comment: I suspect that txs is not calling TL2020, but maybe some older version installed on your system. You can pass path also in txs (Options/Configure menu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is your problem: `I've added the paths to my .bashrc`  this is actually wrong.

Yes this works for everything you start from the commandline. But if you start a program like testudio from a menu or by double clicking a file, then `.bashrc` will never be involved.

Solution, also add the PATH change you your `.profile` file, log out and in again.

`.profile` is read/executed at login and all subsequent processes (including `texstudio`) can see the env variables it sets up.

Additionally, as Sigur mentions in a comment, the fact that `texstudio` finds LaTeX, suggests that you now have two LaTeX installations, one from Ubuntu and the upsteam TL2020. This might have come as a suggested bundle when you installed `texstudio` or from earlier work.

Comment: This Worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kijawo2686 just wondering, from where do you have that the path addition had to go into bashrc?

Comment: [A Youtube video](https://youtu.be/nXByzIFIKmk) plus general lack of Understanding about where to  add the $PATH.